# Skipping quartz scheduler for a particular time in a particular day

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

If want to skip scheduler on particular time of particular days.
For example I have following list:

```
 15-June-2015 Time: 4:00 AM to 5:00 AM
 17-June-2015 Time: 12:00 PM to 1:00 PM
 17-July-2015 Time: 11:00 PM to 12:00 AM
 19-August-2015 Time: 12:00 PM to 1:00 PM
 21-November-2015 Time: 7:00 AM to 10:00 PM
```

Which quartz Calendar should I use? Is there any way to achieve this kind of implementation? I know there are different type of calendars available like annual, holiday, cron, weekly, monthly.
But looks like none of them can implement above example.

Comment: what's the logic of above time ?

Comment: Let's assume there is a company where they have specified software release date along with timings. They don't want to run software build on during release time(skip builds). So that time interval needs to be skipped. Now since there is no concrete logic about how they define release timings we cannot assume any particular logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if there is any option in `Quartz Schedular`. But, you can do it in Java. Create one table which will have date and time. And, in your class, check for specific date and time. If matched then skipped the task. See below code.

```
public class SchedularJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        if (checkDateTime()) {
            System.out.println("Skip the job");
        }else{
           System.out.println(" : Job Executed..!!"); // execute your Job.
        }                     

    }

}
```

Let me know for any query.

Comment: That's perfect answer I was looking for. I kept on thinking of how should I use quart API (modifiedByCalendar). But never thought that I can create a API myself and skip the scheduler.  Thanks jWeaver.